# BigQuery: Failed to create view. Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to save a view in BigQuery, and keep getting the same error:

```
Failed to create view. Unexpected. Please try again.
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
interaction.id AS Interaction.ID,
interaction.author.name AS Interaction.Author.Name,
interaction.author.username AS Interaction.Author.Username,
interaction.content AS Interaction.Content,
interaction.created_at_timestamp AS Interaction.Created_At_Timestamp,
klout.score AS Klout.Score,
twitter.geo.latitude AS Twitter.Geo.Latitude,
twitter.geo.longitude AS Twitter.Geo.Longitude,
twitter.media.expanded_url AS Twitter.Media.ExpandedUrl,
twitter.media.type AS Twitter.Media.Type,
twitter.place.country AS Twitter.Place.Country,
twitter.user.followers_count AS Twitter.User.Followers,
twitter.user.friends_count AS Twitter.User.Friends,
twitter.user.listed_count AS Twitter.User.Listed,
twitter.retweet.count AS Twitter.Retweet.Count
FROM
[**DATASET_NAME_OMITTED**.main_table]
WHERE
(interaction.id IS NOT NULL)
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp IS NOT NULL)
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp >= DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(UTC_USEC_TO_HOUR(NOW())), -1, "DAY"))
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp < USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(UTC_USEC_TO_HOUR(NOW())))
```

The query validates, and runs without any problems:

```
Valid: This query will process 203 MB when run.
```

I did notice that the twitter.media is of type REPEATED RECORD.  That said, removing twitter.media.* fields does not fix the issue.

I have been able to successfully save other views with the same timestamp restrictions and naming conventions.  Attempting to save this one consistently fails.

For context: This table is populated by DataSift via their BigQuery connector (default, catch-all schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really weird.
I ran an experiment and pulled out each of the alias operations, and it worked.
I then slowly added some of them back in, and again; it continued working. However it seems that certain aliases do not want to work (I have no idea why).
I ended up with the following, which contains most of your aliases, and seems to work as expected:

```
SELECT
interaction.id AS Interaction.ID,
interaction.author.name AS Interaction.Author.Name,
interaction.author.username AS Interaction.Author.Username,
interaction.content AS Interaction.Content,
interaction.created_at_timestamp AS Interaction.Created_At_Timestamp,
klout.score AS Klout.Score,
twitter.geo.latitude AS Twitter.Geo.Latitude,
twitter.geo.longitude AS Twitter.Geo.Longitude,
twitter.media.expanded_url,
twitter.media.type AS Twitter.Media.Type,
twitter.place.country AS Twitter.Place.Country,
twitter.user.followers_count,
twitter.user.friends_count,
twitter.user.listed_count,
twitter.retweet.count AS Twitter.Retweet.Count
FROM [**DATASET_NAME_OMITTED**.main_table] 
WHERE
(interaction.id IS NOT NULL)
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp IS NOT NULL)
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp >= DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(UTC_USEC_TO_HOUR(NOW())), -1, "DAY"))
AND (interaction.created_at_timestamp < USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(UTC_USEC_TO_HOUR(NOW())))
```

What seems really weird is that there is no pattern between what will, and will not work. The `twitter.user.*` fields are integers, but will not accept aliases, however the integer field `klout.score` field does accept an integer.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, and narrowing down the problem.  The aliases as I have them are not set in stone and as such this is not a full-stop problem for me. It would, however, be good to get someone from Google to take a look and let us know what the underlying issue is.